# What is the significance of port number in localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, apache, localhost

Different websites uses different ports, like Codecademy uses `localhost:8000` in its AngularJS and Ruby On Rails tutorials. So, I want to know what is the use of this `8000` in `localhost:8000`. Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is not specific to one framework, it's a much lower level.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_%28computer_networking%29):

> In computer networking, a port is a software construct serving as a communications endpoint in a computer's host operating system. A port is always associated with an IP address of a host and the protocol type of the communication. It completes the destination or origination address of a communications session. A port is identified for each address and protocol by a 16-bit number, commonly known as the port number.
>
> Specific, well-known port numbers are often used to identify specific applications and services. Of the thousands of enumerated ports, 1024 well-known port numbers are reserved by convention to identify specific service types on a host. The protocols that primarily use ports are the Transport Layer protocols, such as the Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) and the User Datagram Protocol (UDP) of the Internet Protocol Suite.
>
> In the client-server model of application architecture, ports are used to provide a multiplexing service on each port number that network clients connect to for service initiation, after which communication is reestablished on another connection-specific port number.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, there's a task runner like grunt or gulp serving the page via BrowserSync (or similar). They use a different port than 80 to not interfere with an already occupied port by a local web server (apache, nginx,...).

Answer (score 0):

This is just a port which rails is listening to. It depends on how you configure your rails server, and, IMHO does not mean anything useful. Sometimes you have to assign service to a different port because default port is occupied by some other service. Sometimes it is done by security reasons, so the hacker from outside world has to know the port you are using. But it's actually not very hard to know

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what the others have said:  all network communications require an ip address (which can be got from a domain name like www.google.com) and a port number.  However, if a port number is not supplied then the http server uses the default:  this is usually port 80.  So, if you were to go to "localhost" without a port, you are effectively saying "localhost:80".  Your computer probably doesn't know what to do with this.  If you say "localhost:8000", and there's a rails server there, then it will handle the request.